# turtlebot charging without battery

Tags: turtlebot, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately my turtlebot was delivered without the additional battery: 4S2P (4400 mAh) that has to be connected in the bottom of the kobuki base.
Is there any way to charge the turtlebot 2 with Kobuki base without this battery.
I tried to charge the turtlebot with the adapter which plugs in next to the on/off switch, but this doesn't work.
I also tried to charge it via the docking station, but also without success.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270751/turtlebot-charging-without-battery/) by [stijndelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30093/stijndelo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no battery in the turtlebot base other than the one you plug into it at the bottom.

If you don't have that, you have no battery, and nothing will charge.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0